# KDE 5 Plasma problems

Tags: opensuse, kde5

I installed KDE 5 Plasma on my openSuSE Tumbleweed machine, and now i'm having problems where it doesn't display anything whatsoever, except a blank desktop.

Is there some sort of "default packages" archive?

Any help is grately appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: I would add the _opensuse_ tag to your question.

Answer (score 0):

As of an update I did today I have this issue on one monitor. What I did to make it usable for now is to log off (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Del</kbd> does display on the blacked out monitor) and log in with IceWM instead.

Hopefully a fix is released soon.

You might also try, after logging in with ice, deleting `.local/share/kscreen` then logout and log back in with plasma. This is working for me, but only works until the next log out.